Mergin Maps layers not appearing
My KMZ files are not showing up on Mergin Maps I have been using Mergin Maps to log data when walking for a project I am completing. In order to track my progress I have also been using MapMyWalk to track which areas I have gone to. I then download these paths as KMZ files and input them into QGIS where they show up perfectly. I sync my QGIS and Mergin Maps and then the names of the KMZ files I input show up as layers on mergin maps but they are not visible and appear with a feature ID of zero. Does anyone have any idea why this may be happening. I have saved these downloaded KMZ files to the same folder as the remainder of my map which is showing up in the Mergin Maps software.

Have you tried converting the KMZ to another file format?
